# Android app crash on query statement

Tags: android

i made a method to query and return the result of a database. When this method runs once it reaches the cursor line the whole program crashes.

This is the line where it crashes:

Cursor item = rDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, "_id like '1'", null, null, null, null);

the columns is a string and i have a column called _id.
I can't see anything wrong with the syntax, please help!

Variables in database class:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "restaurants";

//Database Columns
public static final String COLUMN_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_TELEPHONE = "phone_number";
public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL ="email";
public static final String COLUMN_MENUURL = "menu_address";
public static final String COLUMN_WEBSITE = "website_address";
public static final String COLUMN_MOBILE = "mobile number";

//Database Table Create Statement
private static final String DATABASE_TABLECREATE = "create table "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + COLUMN_ROWID
        + " integer not null, " 
        + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null, " 
        + COLUMN_TELEPHONE + " integer not null, "
        + COLUMN_EMAIL + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_MENUURL + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_WEBSITE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_MOBILE + " integer not null) ;";

//the database itself
private SQLiteDatabase rDb;
```

COlumns:

```
String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_ROWID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TELEPHONE, COLUMN_EMAIL,     COLUMN_MENUURL, COLUMN_WEBSITE, COLUMN_MOBILE};
```

11-05 16:15:05.633: D/gralloc_goldfish(882): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-05 16:15:07.533: D/Button(882): Clicked
11-05 16:15:07.553: D/string declared(882): just before query
11-05 16:15:07.553: D/AndroidRuntime(882): Shutting down VM
11-05 16:15:07.553: W/dalvikvm(882): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at com.example.testforthingy.RestaurantDatabase.getData(RestaurantDatabase.java:107)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at com.example.testforthingy.RestaurantDisplay$1.onClick(RestaurantDisplay.java:26)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-05 16:15:07.564: E/AndroidRuntime(882):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
public String getData(){
    String rName= "";
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_ROWID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TELEPHONE, COLUMN_EMAIL, COLUMN_MENUURL, COLUMN_WEBSITE, COLUMN_MOBILE};

    Cursor item = rDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, "name like 'Terry'", null, null, null, null);

    for(item.moveToFirst();item.moveToNext(); item.isAfterLast()) {
        rName = item.getString(item.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
    }

    return rName;
```

Comment: stack trace. values of the variables (all of them). -1 until then.

Comment: what variables would you like? all the database ones, or every one in the program?

Comment: `rDb`, `DATABASE_TABLE`, `columns`, since those are the ones we see so far. The stacktrace is very important, too.

Comment: i am very new to java what is a "stack trace"

Comment: The big red chunk of exeption stuff in the logcat. Also, the 'value' for `rDb` would be its actual value when you execute your program. You can log it, debug and look what it value is ... The important thing is to make sure it is not null and it is opened. If you are very new I assume you are following a tutorial. could you post the url ?

Comment: i am using a couple of books that i bought and the database does have values in the table i have checked

Comment: This is a stacktrace. The important line is the first with the name of your package in it : `NullPointerException (...) at com.example.testforthingy.RestaurantDatabase.getData(RestaurantDatabase.java:107)`. Now, assuming the line 107 is the one you posted first, the only null object is `rDb`, hence my question : did you check that it was not null, and how do you assign it?

Comment: but the database has records so how can it be null?

Comment: there is absolutely no relation between the `rDb` variable and your actual database until you make it so. post the line preceding the crash (the whole getData method).

Comment: done that now, is there anything wrong with the syntax

Comment: the only thing is that you don't seem to open the database. can you post the part where you do that ?

Comment: oh i presumed that was automatic.  That must be what's missing. How would i write that and where?

Answer (score 0):

_id is an integer, not a string. And columns must be of type String[], not String, otherwise your code would not even compile. So I suggest you try:

```
Cursor item = rDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, "_id=1", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: sorry to say but this yielded the same result